# sqlalchemy dumps where is manage.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to get alchemydumps to backup my database and am getting the following error when trying to run the alchemydumps create command. I think it is caused by a many to many relationship bug, but am unsure.

```
 File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3971, in __init__
"expected - got '%r'" % (column, )
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '<class 'flask_sqlalchemy.Model'>'
```

[Alchemy dumps documents](https://github.com/cuducos/alchemydumps)

manage.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_alchemydumps import AlchemyDumps, AlchemyDumpsCommand
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# init Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

#SQL Alchemy Database config location
if os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') is None:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = ('sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db') +
                               '?check_same_thread=False')
else:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']


# init SQLAlchemy and Flask-Script
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
manager = Manager(app)

@manager.command
def hello():
    print "hello"

# init Alchemy Dumps
alchemydumps = AlchemyDumps(app, db)
manager.add_command('alchemydumps', AlchemyDumpsCommand)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

Traceback:

```
(env) jsnyder10@jsnyder10-VirtualBox:~/Documents/45$ flask/bin/python manage.py alchemydumps create
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 36, in <module>
    manager.run()
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 412, in run
    result = self.handle(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 383, in handle
    res = handle(*args, **config)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_script/commands.py", line 216, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_alchemydumps/__init__.py", line 48, in create
    data = alchemy.get_data()
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_alchemydumps/helpers/database.py", line 36, in get_data
    query = db.session.query(model)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 157, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1330, in query
    return self._query_cls(entities, self, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 139, in __init__
    self._set_entities(entities)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 148, in _set_entities
    entity_wrapper(self, ent)
  File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3971, in __init__
    "expected - got '%r'" % (column, )
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '<class 'flask_sqlalchemy.Model'>'
```

Comment: That README isn't explicit about it, but `manage.py` is the suggested/conventional name of a module one creates using `Flask-Script` to help manage a Flask application.  You'll find a good explanation in [the `Flask-Script` docs](http://flask-script.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks for the help, that was driving me crazy that they kept using manage.py without ever showing where it came from.